# Nginx reverse proxy from a container to another container returns 404 in a Laravel app

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

First, let me state that I have been working on this problem for a few days and the tried many solutions. There are two services `user` and `diet`. This is the diet docker-compose file

```
version: '3'
networks:
  common_network:
    external: true
  diet_network:
    name: diet_network
    driver: bridge

services:
  diet_php:
     ...
  diet_nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: nginx.Dockerfile
    container_name: diet_nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: diet_nginx
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "8015:80"
    networks:
      - diet_network
      - common_network
    depends_on:
      - diet_php
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
  diet_mysql:
    - ...

volumes:
  mysqldata:
    driver: local
```

and this is the user docker-compose file and `default.conf`

```
version: '3'

networks:
  common_network:
    external: true
  user_network:
    name: user_network
    driver: bridge

services:
  user_php:
     ...
  user_nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: nginx.Dockerfile
    container_name: user_nginx
    image: user_nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "8014:80"
    networks:
      - user_network
      - common_network
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - user_php
  user_mysql:
       ...

volumes:
  mysqldata:
    driver: local
```

This is the `default.conf` of the user service

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/html/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
    client_max_body_size 64M;

    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }



    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass user_php:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;

    }

    location /diet {
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass          http://diet_nginx;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

The `diet_nginx` and `user_nginx` can ping each other inside the container and it is OK. I need to make an HTTP request from the user service to the diet service. This is a route in `api.php` of user service

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return 'default index';
});

Route::get('/hello-world', function () {
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
//    $res = $client->get('user_nginx/api');
    $res = $client->get('user_nginx/diet/api/hello');
    return $res;
});
```

and the route in `api.php` of the diet service

```
Route::get('/hello', function () {
    return 'hi!';
});
```

I am sure this route exists and `http://localhost:8015/api/hello` returns the response. **However, the calling route `http://localhost:8014/api/hello-world` of the user service doesn't work and returns a 404 not found error.**

It is worthwhile to mention that the commented line

```
$res = $client->get('user_nginx/api');
```

works and returns a response.

Comment: instead of `user_nginx` Change to `http://localhost:port_no`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who will see this in the future, I changed the proxy pass to follows and it worked

```
location /diet/ {
    proxy_pass   http://diet_nginx/;
}
```